# Transmission-daemon: cannot edit settings.json

Tags: permissions, bittorrent, transmission

I want to edit Transmission-daemon's main config file located at `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` but I am unable to, due to its default permissions:

```
/etc/transmission-daemon$ ls -lah
total 16K
drwxrwsr-x   2 root                debian-transmission 4.0K Mar 19 12:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 103 root                root                4.0K Mar 19 12:28 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root                root                 303 Dec 19  2021 README.json
-rw-------   1 debian-transmission debian-transmission 2.4K Mar 19 12:28 settings.json
```

I'm new to Transmission so, assuming the user is supposed to edit settings.json, what is the safest way to allow editing?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- transmission-daemon 3.00 (bb6b5a062e)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`settings.json` is owned by the `debian-transmission` user and group, you should just use sudo to grant you the full rights, for example if you want to open the file with a text editor like `nano` do `sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`
```

Once you have modified the file, restart `transmission` like that `sudo systemctl restart transmission-daemon`